# 10 seconds timeout on wp-admin page on an offline install

Tags: php, wordpress, timeout

I have an offline WordPress site working fine on my LAN. My only problem is that it seems there's a timeout (approximately 10s) each time I go into "wp-admin" or change the page in the admin area (themes, settings, etc.).
As it's an offline install, I guess WordPress is trying to reach WordPress servers to check for updates, etc., and can not reach it (obviously), which results in a 10s hang when going into wp-admin.

I'm sorry, I couldn't find any help online: are there any settings where I can tell WordPress it's an offline install and not try to reach the internet (or at least reduce the timeout to a minimum ?).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried to disable automatic update and other checks?

Comment: I did, but unfortunately, it doesn't change anything. I tried to set "AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED" to true and "WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE" to false in the wp-config file. I also used an extension to disable all auto update of themes and plugin. I still have a 10s hang when I load a page within the wp-admin area.